# Caracteres aleatorios al final de string

Tags: c, string

He hecho dos funciones de cifrado simple de strings en C. Parece que vaya bien pero a la hora de mostrar por pantalla el resultado se añaden 2 caracteres aleatorios al final de la string resultante.

La función lo que hace es crear una string nueva, en el primer caracter se almacena el tamaño de la string original (las strings nunca pasarán de 20 o 25 caracteres), en el segundo caracter la key usada (el primer caracter de la string -1) y luego la string cifrada.

El código completo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <string.h> //strlen

char* x(const char* toEncrypt);
char* y(const char* toDecrypt);

int main() {
    const char *secret = "hellohello";
    printf("original: %s\n", secret);

    const char* crypted = x(secret);
    printf("crypted: %s\n", crypted);

    const char* decrypted = y(crypted);
    printf("decrypted: %s\n", decrypted);

    return 0;
}

char* x(const char* toEncrypt) {
    printf("x->toEncrypt = %s\n", toEncrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = strlen(toEncrypt);
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = ((char)(*toEncrypt))-1;
    printf("\tx->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+3); //toEncrypt length + (length + key + null)

    output[offset++] = (char)length;
    output[offset++] = key;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, toEncrypt[i]);
        output[offset++] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
    }
    output[offset] = '\0';

    printf("\tx->output = %s\n", output);
    return output;
}

char* y(const char* toDecrypt) {
    printf("y->toDecrypt = %s\n", toDecrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = (int)toDecrypt[offset++] ;
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = (char)toDecrypt[offset++];
    printf("\ty->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+1);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, (char)toDecrypt[offset] ^key);
        output[i] = toDecrypt[offset++] ^ key;
    }

    output[offset] = '\0';

    printf("\ty->output = %s\n", output);
    return output;
}
```

Y el resultado en consola:

```
original: hellohello
x->toEncrypt = hellohello
        x->length = 10
        x->key = g
i = 0   offset = 2      char = h
i = 1   offset = 3      char = e
i = 2   offset = 4      char = l
i = 3   offset = 5      char = l
i = 4   offset = 6      char = o
i = 5   offset = 7      char = h
i = 6   offset = 8      char = e
i = 7   offset = 9      char = l
i = 8   offset = 10     char = l
i = 9   offset = 11     char = o
        x->output =
g
crypted:
g
y->toDecrypt =
g
        x->length = 10
        y->key = g
i = 0   offset = 2      char = h
i = 1   offset = 3      char = e
i = 2   offset = 4      char = l
i = 3   offset = 5      char = l
i = 4   offset = 6      char = o
i = 5   offset = 7      char = h
i = 6   offset = 8      char = e
i = 7   offset = 9      char = l
i = 8   offset = 10     char = l
i = 9   offset = 11     char = o
        y->output = hellohellobe
decrypted: hellohellobe
```

**EDIT**

Teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de @SJuan76 añadiendo el siguiete código en la función `y`:

`for(i = 0; i < length + 5; i++){
        printf("i = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, output[i]);
    }`

muestra lo siguiente:

`i = 0   char = h
i = 1   char = e
i = 2   char = l
i = 3   char = l
i = 4   char = o
i = 5   char = h
i = 6   char = e
i = 7   char = l
i = 8   char = l
i = 9   char = o
i = 10  char = b
i = 11  char = e
i = 12  char =
i = 13  char = ;
i = 14  char = C`

Comment: "Caracteres raros al imprimir un `char *`" siempre acaba siendo que no pones el `\0` donde toca. Mira cual es el valor de `offset` en `output[offset + 1]`

Comment: Creo que está bien en como pongo el null-char.

Comment: La verdad es que no entendí tu primera respuesta. Probé a iterar output incluso más allá de su longitud y mostrando caracter por caracter y después del null-char salen los caracteres 'b' y 'e', por lo que me parece raro que al usar printf aparezcan caracteres después de un null-char.
Actualizo la pregunta añadiendo prueba.

Comment: A ver, haz printf de `offset` justo antes de `output[offset + 1] = '\0';` en `y()` (el `=\0` se me perdió en el primer comentario).

Comment: El resultado de offset es 12, lo esperado.

Comment: Probaste haciendo un memset antes de llenar la cadena?
`memset(&output[0], 0, sizeof(output));`

Comment: No, lo esperado es 10 porque estás asignando 10 caracteres a una char * de 11 chars... mira el `for` justo de arriba, en `output` está el string original (sin prefijos) y lo asignas a partir de la posición `0`... En otras palabras, en `output` de 0 a 10 está el string original, el `\0` ha de ir en la posición 11. Los caracteres 11 y 12 no los inicializas y por eso te sale la "basurilla".

Answer (score 1):

He podido resolver el problema copiando `output` a una nueva string. El código completo es:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <string.h> //strlen

char* x(const char* toEncrypt);
char* y(const char* toDecrypt);

int main() {
    const char *secret = "hellohello";
    printf("original: %s\n", secret);

    const char* crypted = x(secret);
    printf("crypted: %s\n", crypted);

    const char* decrypted = y(crypted);
    printf("decrypted: %s\n", decrypted);

    return 0;
}

char* x(const char* toEncrypt) {
    printf("x->toEncrypt = %s\n", toEncrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = strlen(toEncrypt);
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = ((char)(*toEncrypt))-1;
    printf("\tx->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+3); //toEncrypt length + (length + key + null)

    output[offset++] = (char)length;
    output[offset++] = key;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, toEncrypt[i]);
        output[offset++] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
    }
    output[offset] = '\0';

    char* realoutput = (char*)malloc(length+3);
    memcpy(realoutput, output, length+3);
    free(output);
    realoutput[length+3] = '\0';

    printf("\tx->output = %s\n", output);
    return realoutput;
}

char* y(const char* toDecrypt) {
    printf("y->toDecrypt = %s\n", toDecrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = (int)toDecrypt[offset++] ;
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = (char)toDecrypt[offset++];
    printf("\ty->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+1);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, (char)toDecrypt[offset] ^key);
        output[i] = toDecrypt[offset++] ^ key;
    }
    printf("offset = %d\n", offset);
    output[offset] = '\0';

    char* realoutput = (char*)malloc(length+1);
    memcpy(realoutput, output, length+1);
    free(output);
    realoutput[length] = '\0';

    printf("\ty->output = %s\n", output);
    return realoutput;
}
```